# Create a list from entries in column

Tags: python

I would like to create a simple list from entries in such format (copied from single Excel column):

```
4,15
3,34
3,33
3,15
```

I would like to replace ',' with '.' for each value and convert it to float.

Comment: You should post an error, not a problem to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the row is a string

```
string_ = "4,15 3,34 3,33 3,15"

list_ = []
for str_ in string_.split(" "):
    str_ = str_.replace(",", ".")
    list_.append(float(str_))
```

with comprehension:

```
[float(str_.replace(",", ".")) for str_ in string_.split(" ")]
```